# How to share a part of the Redux store with all reducers?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am new to Redux, please be gentle.
A part of my store (e.g. state.c) should be editable by all reducers. I guess this [Redux docs article](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/beyondcombinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers) goes in that direction, but I don't get what my rootReducer.js should exactly look like.

I would prefer to have a merged state (e.g. state.a + state.c for reducer A) rather than state.c as action payload.

How do I do that? Can I combine it with combineReducers from Redux?

Comment: Please share your code you got so far in a form of 
 [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this all comes down to your state tree design and how correct is it. if two reducers need to share the same data often, then they probably should be merged.